# Can I stream the MySQL database in flutter?

Tags: mysql, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, backend

In a flutter app stream are used. If some changes happens in firestore database then It'll be reflected in the app too. Can we do the same with the MySQL database as a backend server for storing data. Will the changes in MySQL reflected in the flutter app too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL does not have built-in realtime capabilities like Firestore.  Firestore is fairly unique in this way.  Typically, with SQL type databases, you have to repeat the query ("polling the database") to find any updates.  There might be other middleware products you can use to simulate realtime updates, but you would have to search for and evaluate those for yourself.